# How can I find the source of a ping request within a device?

Tags: networking, ip, ping

I have a linux-based cellular device that every 4-6 weeks begins pinging Google IP addresses 10-12x every minute. This increased pinging begins and ends seemingly randomly, lasts for a few days before returning to normal (i.e., no pinging), and the ping requests appear to receive successful responses without exception. The IP addresses used for the requests change each time a new increase in ping activity begins although the pings appear to always use Google addresses.

Is there any way to find the application/program that is initiating the pings on my device? I ran

```
grep -r "Google"
```

hoping to find a list or database of some sort which the device uses as a source for the different IP addresses, but have not had any luck. Any suggestions/feedback/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you use chrome (a.k.a.: chromium, the google provided web navigator)  in your device ?

Comment: What OS android or other? (it may be relevant)

Comment: Do you have CONFIG_FTRACE enabled in your kernel? You might have a copy of the config in /boot, or you can run `mount -t debugfs debugfs /sys/kernel/debug` to check,

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that ftrace is configured in the kernel and you have root access you can use the kernel tracing facilities.

There are newer tools available, in particular bpftrace, but embedded devices often lack the needed space to install the needed dependencies. This solution uses ftrace which has been available for many years.
This is just using the raw files, there are tools which will automate some of these steps.

If the debugfs is not already mounted then mount it

```
[ -e /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/README ] || mount -t debugfs debugfs /sys/kernel/debug
```

Disable tracing, set the report to trace functions, set the functions to monitor

```
 cd /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
 echo 0 > tracing_on
 echo function > current_tracer
 echo ping_init_sock > set_ftrace_filter
 echo sock_sendmsg >> set_ftrace_filter # Optional, omit if ping_init_sock gives results
```

Enable tracing

```
 echo 1 > tracing_on
```

wait for the `ping` events to happen, then examine what is in the `trace` file.

```
cat trace
# tracer: function
#
# entries-in-buffer/entries-written: 56/56   #P:1
#
#                              _-----=> irqs-off
#                             / _----=> need-resched
#                            | / _---=> hardirq/softirq
#                            || / _--=> preempt-depth
#                            ||| /     delay
#           TASK-PID   CPU#  ||||    TIMESTAMP  FUNCTION
#              | |       |   ||||       |         |
            ping-3085  [000] .... 8035797.349326: ping_init_sock <-inet_create
            ping-3085  [000] .... 8035797.349352: ping_init_sock <-inet6_create
            ping-3085  [000] .... 8035797.349739: sock_sendmsg <-___sys_sendmsg
            ping-3085  [000] .... 8035797.349764: sock_sendmsg <-___sys_sendmsg
            ping-3085  [000] .... 8035797.365248: sock_sendmsg <-__sys_sendto
            ping-3085  [000] .... 8035797.365486: sock_sendmsg <-__sys_sendto
            ping-3085  [000] .... 8035797.379917: sock_sendmsg <-__sys_sendto
            ping-3085  [000] .... 8035797.387487: sock_sendmsg <-__sys_sendto
```

which show that PID 3085 is doing the ping. If you are lucky the process that does the pinging will be still running so you can find it in the `ps` output. If not then you may hope for it to have a recognizable name.

Failing both of those, then maybe https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/deprecated/execsnoop-proc can help.